# List has no row exception: Queryerror

Tags: query, error, list, error-messages

I have below line placed in controller that fires list has no row exception. I just need to show a custom message instead when the query returns no value.

**Apex code:**

```
Id CI=[select Compliance_Incident_abv__c from Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Name=:selectedCIT].Compliance_Incident_abv__c ;  //**This line throws error**
    system.debug('CI@@'+CI);
        if(cond != '')
            cond += ' and';  
        else
            cond += ' where ';                            
           if(CI!=null) 
        cond += ' Id = \'' + CI+ '\'';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because if your query doesn't contain any row it will throw exception to solve this update your code to

```
id ci;
List<Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c > CIList=[select Compliance_Incident_abv__c from Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Name=:selectedCIT]

if(CIList.size() > 0)
  ci = CIList[0].Compliance_Incident_abv__c;
```

Always you use List to query instead of single variable for better practices until you have some strong reasons.